# How to resize an lvm volume (after lvresize got corrupted. is it possible to revert?)?

Tags: partitioning, debian, mount, lvm

I did following under the `root` login (shrinking `/home`, expanding `/var`):

> umount /home
>   lvresize -L-7G /dev/mapper/myvg-home

it was warning:

```
WARNING: Reducing active logical volume to 28.89 GiB
THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
```

I thought it is usual warning and accepted

Then I done:

```
> lvresize -L+7G /dev/mapper/myvg-var
```

It was successfully done:

```
Extending logical volume var to 9.79 GiB
Logical volume var successfully resized
```

But as I saw the `/var` didn't expanded if looking with `df -h`. I thought the reboot will solve the problem.

Then I tried to mount the home partition back:

```
> mount /home
```

And I got an error:

```
 mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/myvg-home,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Then I rebooted the machine. Afterwards I got:

```
/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
Welcome to emergency mode. Use "systemctl default" or ^D to activate default
mode.
Give root password for maintenance
(or type Control-D to continue):
```

So I entered the maintenance console and ran:

```
> fsck /dev/mapper/myvg-home
```

But after some questions about errors and whether I would like to abort the operations I got a new error:

```
fsck.ext4: Can't read an block bitmap while retrying to read bitmaps for /dev/mapper/myvg-home
e2fsck: aborted
```

So I cannot get the system running. What is the problem and what did I wrong when tried to resize the lvm partitions? It is just unmount, resize and mount back again, isn't it?

**Is it possible to recover the partition or at least to create a new and get the system running back, or does it require some special operations to create a new home partition?**

Comment: When you `lvresize` you're only resizing the virtual volume. The actual file system partition isn't affected. You still need to resize it with `resize2fs` before the space shows up in `df`. Similarly, you'll first want to shrink your partition before you shrink the volume the partition resides on.

Comment: so, is it possible to recover the `/home` with the files there? I recovered using the `vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive/my-vg_00002-692643462.vg  my-vg`, so `lvs` shows now the previous partition table. But if I try to mount `home` I get the same error message: `mount: wrong fs type, ...`.

Comment: First shrink the file system, then shrink the lvm. For expasion, expand the lvm first, then expand the file system.

Comment: You need to use lvresize -r to resize the file system at same time. Basically you only modified LV size but the file system still at old size.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can fix it!
Run the inverse commands back.

After `lvresize -L-7G /dev/mapper/myvg-home`
run   `lvresize -L+7G /dev/mapper/myvg-home`

After `lvresize -L+7G /dev/mapper/myvg-var`
run   `lvresize -L-7G /dev/mapper/myvg-var`

You may even had an unsuccessful boot inbetween, this is fine. After fixing the sizes you can reboot and observe that all your partitions are working again. Time to do what you wanted originally, but correctly this time. For that, add the `--resizefs` key to all of your commands:

```
lvresize --size -7G /dev/mapper/myvg-home --resizefs
lvresize --size +7G /dev/mapper/myvg-var --resizefs
```

This operation will take a while to execute because your data would need to be moved around, as usual with resizing partitions. After that, you can reboot and use your partitions as usual (or not reboot and use right away, but chances are you're using a LiveUSB stick to fix/resize the main OS).

Hope this helps! I've encountered this myself today  and this fixed the issue.